# Communication between React native and existing app IOS

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

i'm pretty new to Swift and react native . 
I'm trying to integrate react native in the existing IOS app and documentation is not very clear on one point : let's say i start an app with React Native from appDelegate (smth like that)

```
let rootView: RCTRootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleName: "MainScreen", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions: launchOptions)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let rootViewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    rootViewController.view = rootView

    self.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

works perfectly, i can see my React Native app but when i want to go to native part , to native screen, it's not very clear how to make this segue working. I made a native module class which i can access from react native but i don't understand how to call a native View controller from there or should i close react rootController or what?

i've tried smth like

let vc = FirstViewController() //destination controller
    delegate.rootViewController!.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

this one somehow don't initialise buttons and stuff and gives me a lot of nils
So my question is how to go from react to native and back?
Any tips would be very helpful!